# Como alterar rota em execução?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Uso MVC5 e Visual Studio 2013. Criei essa rota: `Home/PaginaBase`. Essa rota chama uma nova página, chamada `PaginaBase`, que possui cabeçalho e rodapé semelhante a `Index`. Esse rodapé cria um Menu. Quando seleciono um item desse menu, ele me chama a `PaginaBase`, montando a URL assim:

> http://www.localhost:58686/Home/PaginaBase/6/3.

Até aí, ok. Quando vou selecionar outro item (continuo dentro da `PaginaBase`), ele mantém a mesma URL na chamada e acrescenta outra vez `Home/PaginaBase/8/3`, aí fica uma rota inexistente. Como eu resolvo isso?

Abaixo minha função jquery

```js
function MontaMenuInferior() {

    var str = "";
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/MontaMenuInferior',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {

            $(data.resultado).each(function () {

                str = str + '<ul class="grid_4">' +
                                    '<li>' + this.SubCategoria + '</li>';


                $(this.subconsulta).each(function () {

                    if (this.Id_SubCategoria2 != null) 

                        str = str + '<li><a href="Home/PaginaBase/' + this.Id_SubCategoria2 + '/3" title="">' + this.SubCategoria2 + '</a></li>';
                        //str = str + '<li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl(PaginaBase"',new{ Parametro : this.Id_SubCategoria2, tipo : '3'} + ")">this.SubCategoria2 + '</a>'
                    else
                        str = str + '<li><a href="#' + this.SubCategoria2 + '" title="">' + this.SubCategoria2 + '</a></li>';

                });

                str = str + '</ul>';

                $('#menufooter').append(str);

                str = "";

            });
        },
        error: function (error) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Pra quê esses números no final das suas URLs? Não seria melhor apenas usar os nomes devidos das views?

Comment: Como assim? Esses números são parâmetros que passo para chamar determinados html. São ID's do bd.

Comment: O problema da duplicação, é que estava faltando uma barra na chamada do link, tipo: /Home/PaginaBase... e não Home/PaginaBase.... Isso já resolvi, agora me chamaou a atenção com relação ao nome sugerido pelo Tiago.

Answer (score 1):

Você está usando URLs relativas nos seus links. Se você está em `/Home/PaginaBase/6/3` (i.e. este é seu ***path***) e você clica num link para `Home/PaginaBase/8/3` seu novo *path* vai ser `/Home/PaginaBase/6/3/Home/PaginaBase/8/3`.

Se usar URLs relativas ele vai **substituir** seu *path* em vez de concatenar a ele: `/Home/PaginaBase/8/3` (note a `/` no começo).

> P.S. Dei [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22522953/520779) na [sua pergunta no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22300092/520779) antes de ler [seu comentário dizendo que já havia achado o problema](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8719/como-alterar-rota-em-execucao#comment14891_8719).